# Thingsboard shared attribute

Tags: javascript, html, widget, thingsboard

I'm working with thingsboard and I want to change a device shared attribute by clicking on a button and when I click  a popup appear for confirmation, I  know that I can create a **custom action in a widget with html template**  but  am not familiar with javascript, html and CSS and I need to implement that in **html card**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with web technologies just use one on attribute's widgets from *Input bundle*

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,i already Know that WE Can change attributes with input widget , but i'am working on HTML card . Thank you again

Comment: Unfortunately, HTML widget doesn't support any API manipulation.